# Radius of Convergence for $\cosh(n)z^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I wish to find the radius of convergence for

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \cos(in)z^n $$ that is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \cosh(n)z^n $

but when i use the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem i get stuck with:

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty}  \sqrt[n]{\cosh(n)}=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{e^n+e^{-n}} 2}$$ but i don't know how to evaluate this

I also tried 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{\left|\cosh(n+1)\right|}{\left|\cosh(n)\right|}<1$$

but I just get stuck with

$$\frac{|ee^n+\frac{1}{e}e^{-n}|}{|e^n+e^{-n}|}<1 $$

how do I find the radius of convergence if this series?

Comment: Notice that

$$\left(\frac{e^n + e^{-n}}{2}\right)^{1/n} = e \cdot \left(\frac{1 + e^{-2n}}{2}\right)^{1/n} \to e$$

as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: thank you, I've missed that